# jalert not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have following script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 jAlert("message","title");
</script>
```

in my html head.but the dialog is not showing up when I load the page(it would if I simply use alert).

where did I do wrong? Am I missing the corresponding js files?

edit: I included the jquery.alerts.js file.it is still not working.

edit: I added this line and put the file in the dir

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.alerts.js"></script>
```

Yes I put it inbetween.

I opened the browser console and saw this:

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollHeight' of null        jquery-1.8.2.js:9405"

Comment: You have included the jQuery source, but I see no `<script>` tag including the jAlert source.

Comment: Please update your code above to reflect your changes.

Comment: Did you put this between the jquery include, and your script? (It's needs jquery to work, and your script needs jalerts to work) - I've updated my answer to add more clarity to the comment.

Comment: I'm afraid it works for me - so you've done something odd. It's hard to say what from here, but I would start by double checking your filenames. (You are definitely using jquery version 1.8.2 etc) What browser are you using as well? (Not that it should matter)

Comment: My jquery version is correct.

Comment: FOUND IT :D It can't be run before the DOM loads - so wrap it in a ready function like I have updated my answer to show. You'll only need to do this when it comes up immediately (it won't matter if you're clicking a button, or doing form validation etc)

Comment: My full code is in my answer. But here is a jsfiddle (which is better for code than justpaste.it) http://jsfiddle.net/XzfHG/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

jAlert isn't a part of native jQuery.

You can find the project page [here](http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/12/jquery-alert-dialogs/), the download link is at the bottom.

Make sure you include it straight after jQuery - your code should look as follows:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.alerts.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.alerts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
      jAlert("message","title")
 });
</script>
```